# No idea why VBA No longer Inserting Form data into designate excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I created a form to collect data, and during the whole testing Phase the code below was working fine, but all of a sudden it's throwing this error:  [image]

This is the code, It was working fine for a while, any idea what might have gone wrong??

```
Private Sub cmdSave_GotFocus()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If ValidateForm = True Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
            .Range("A" & iRow).Value = iRow - 1
            .Range("B" & iRow).Value = txtInitials.Value
            .Range("C" & iRow).Value = txtStoreNo.Value
            .Range("D" & iRow).Value = cmbLocation.Text
            .Range("E" & iRow).Value = IIf(optNew.Value = True, "New", "Existing")
            .Range("F" & iRow).Value = txtOpenDate.Value
            .Range("G" & iRow).Value = txtRequestDate.Value
            .Range("H" & iRow).Value = txtPosition.Value
            .Range("I" & iRow).Value = IIf(optFullTime = True, "Full-Time", "Part-Time")
            .Range("J" & iRow).Value = TxtNotes.Value
        End With
            MsgBox ("Submission Successful. Thank You!")
        Call Reset
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True`enter code here` 
    End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what code line is sending the error?

Comment: Did you happen to change the name of your worksheet from `Data` to something else?

Comment: Hooded 0ne the line throwing the error was .Range("A" & iRow).Value = iRow - 1

Comment: dwirony I did not change the Data worksheet name at the time, but in my desperate attempt I went ahead and created a different sheet and applied the same exact code. It's working now, so something I did on the sheet must have thrown it off, but I still don't know why it happened.